# Copy/Paste files through CMD with Date appended into pasted files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P parent_folder=Please specify parent directory: 
SET /P destination_folder=Please specify destination: 
set NOW=%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%--%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
FOR %%n in (%parent_folder%*.*) DO (
  copy "%%n" "%destination_folder%" 
  set /A count+=1
)
```

It is not working so far. If someone makes it work, I can append date to the `%destination_folder%` to get my results.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Are the files not being copied? Is just the appending of the date missing? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the timestamp to the destination file names like this:

```
for %%n in ("%parent_folder%\*.*") do (
  copy "%%~n" "%destination_folder%\%%~nn_%NOW%%%~xn"
  set /a count+=1
)
```